# Oracle Left outer joins using old syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

So, I've been trying to do following outer joins:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2
ON table1.a = table2.a
AND table1.b = table2.b
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3
ON table1.a  =  table3.a
AND table1.b = table3.c
```

I've tested and could do it with no problems. However, the software I'm using uses the older syntax for left joins. And so I wrote it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2, table3
WHERE table1.a = table2.a  (+)
AND table1.b   = table2.b (+)
AND table1.c = table3.a (+) 
AND table2.c =  table3.b (+)
```

Obviously, I get the ORA-01417: a table may be outer joined to at most one other table error. Any way to workaround this issue?

table1.c is not present in any table2 columns, so I'm forced to use the table1.c =  table3.b clause.

Comment: Use subqueries.  Then update your software so you don't have to use archaic syntax.

Comment: Actually, I don't see how your query gives you the ORA-01417 error. It should work as is.  Are you sure you typed it correctly?

Comment: @sstan - this is a stylized example, the OP probably didn't catch the problem quite right. It would help if he/she would show the actual setup rather than a made-up one (which, as you point out, does NOT reproduce the problem).

Comment: In practice it may not be helpful for you but, 12c adds support for outer joins to multiple tables with the (+) syntax.

Comment: I'm sorry, there was a little typo in the 2nd query. I corrected it now.